# Can we enable TLS 1.2 on SQL Server 2017 and still allow clients to connect without encryption?

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2, sql-server-2017

We have a SQL Server 2017 setup where existing clients and applications connect to it using JDBC and normal connection port.

We now have a requirement from one of the clients to use TLS. I want to know if we can enable TLS 1.2 on our SQL Server instance such that our existing clients and applications continue to work without any changes/issues.

Having checked the MS SQL documentation for enabling TLS, I cannot deduce clearly if the normal connection will stop working after enabling TLS.

All I can see from documentation is that when enabling TLS there is a property FORCE ENCRYPTION that has to be set to True. Does that disable normal ports and existing clients cannot connect without adding the secure connection parameters?

One of the articles I read mentioned the text as (and that is what makes me a bit nervous)

> To enable encryption, we will install a Transport Layer Security (TLS) certificate on SQL Server, configure the SQL Server instance to use this certificate, and enforce encryption so that communication between the SQL Server and the client application is always secured. Once encryption is forced, beware that SQL Server will start rejecting client connections that do not support encryption. Thus, it is important that you first try these steps in a development or staging environment to avoid downtime of your production system

Comment: What has your research shown you? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well, our DBA says it is not possible and once TLS is enabled, the normal connections cannot work. I am wondering if that is the case and wanted to check with the community.

Comment: Why not check the documentation rather than a community?

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I did try to read through the MS SQL documentation for enabling TLS. It is not very clear on this or may be I am not able to comprehend it that clearly. All I see is that when enabling TLS there is a property FORCE ENCRYPTION that has to be set to True,  But that is what I am confused about. Does that disable normal ports and existing clients cannot connect?

Comment: Update your question with those clarifications

Comment: TLS 1.2 is enabled by default on SQL Server 2016 and later. If you have an SQL Server 2017 installation that can't accept connections using TLS 1.2 then you've got other problems with your infrastructure. If one of your clients wants to use encrypted connections then they can **opt-in** to that by adding `;Encrypt=True/Yes` in their connection strings and potentially `;Trust_Server_Certificate=True/Yes` if your instance is using a self-signed certificate - it won't affect any other connecting clients.